# How to remove a specific image from a PDF with PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I need to remove a specific image from PDF file according its metadata. Sadly. all examples I can find in Internet are using discarded methods.

I write it something like this:

```
try (PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(pdf))) {
doc.getPages().forEach(page ->
{
    PDResources resources = page.getResources();
    List<COSName> itemsToRemove = new ArrayList<>();

    resources.getXObjectNames().forEach(propertyName -> {
        if(!resources.isImageXObject(propertyName)) {
            return;
        }
        PDXObject pdxObject = resources.getXObject(propertyName);
        PDImageXObject pdImageXObject = (PDImageXObject)pdxObject;
        PDMetadata metadata = pdImageXObject.getMetadata();
        if(checkMetadata(metadata)){
            // What should I use here?
            page.getCOSObject().removeItem(propertyName);
        }
    });
    // Should I use page.setResources(resources); ?
 });
doc.save(baos);
} catch (Exception e) {
//Code here
```

}

Comment: You can remove it from the XObject dictionary in the resources dictionary. But that is only a part of it... you'll have to remove it from the content stream as well, i.e. at the places there image is invoked. You'd have to modify the RemoveAllText example to remove that specific image with the name you found. I could try to do some code - are you sure that the "image" is really an image and not some vector graphic? And that it is in the first level of the resources, and not somewhere deep down? Can you share the PDF?

Comment: I'm sure that it's an image, because I'm generating this image with contentStream.drawImage. So, is there any idea, how to remove it from contentStream??

Comment: Just search for "Do" instead of "TJ" and the others; when you hit it, check whether the name (the token before "Do") is the one of the image you want to remove. The RemoveAllText example is in the source code download.

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't help. I search for Do, but only token before "Do" is "cm". When I remove CM, I lose all of the text in document

Comment: At the time you hit "Do", the previous token is `newTokens.get(newTokens.size() - 1);`. In the existing code, that one is removed. Did you do the check before the removal?

Comment: Yep, it was my mistake. I've used type conversion before check and lost some of tags.

Comment: Now it works just fine, thank you!

Comment: Please answer the question yourself with the info you got, I'm too busy :-(

Answer (score 2):

It works same way like it does in example RemoveAllText.java, just with different tag.

Use code from this example, just use "Do" instead of "Tj".

Of course, if you need to load metadata, etc, you should enumerate and check images threw page resources (like in my example)

Comment: RemoveAllText.java: https://github.com/BrentDouglas/pdfbox/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/util/RemoveAllText.java