# How to remove a specific image from a PDF with PDFBox 2.0

Tags: image, pdfbox

In my project, we are using the pdfbox library 2.0 version to manipulate the pdf operations.
Among those in one operation, I have a pdf file having two images on-page. Now what I have to do is,
**remove one specific image from two images and keep others as is and save the document**. But with the code provided in the below link it removing all images from the page.

The expected behavior should be shared in the below link. Please help me with this as I have already spent 3-4 days to achieve this.

[delete am image from a PDF file using PDFbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63598888/delete-am-image-from-a-pdf-file-using-pdfbox)

```
public void removeImages() {
        try {
            PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File("..\\sampleWithImage_with_barcode_img.pdf"));

            PDPageTree page = document.getDocumentCatalog().getPages();
            for (PDPage pdPage : page) {
                removeQRCodeImage(pdPage, SOME_UNIQUE_ID);
            }
        }
        document.save("..\\RemoveImage.pdf");
        document.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

public void removeQRCodeImage(PDPage pdPage, String imgUniqueId) {
    try {
        PDResources pdResources = pdPage.getResources();
        for (COSName c : pdResources.getXObjectNames()) {
            PDXObject o = pdResources.getXObject(c);
            if (o instanceof PDImageXObject) {
                PDImageXObject pdImageXObject = (PDImageXObject) o;
                
                if (pdImageXObject.getMetadata() != null) {
                    DomXmpParser xmpParser = new DomXmpParser();
                    XMPMetadata xmpMetadata = xmpParser.parse(pdImageXObject.getMetadata().toByteArray());
                    if(imgUniqueId.equals(xmpMetadata.getDublinCoreSchema().getTitle()))
                        ((COSDictionary) pdResources.getCOSObject().getDictionaryObject(COSName.XOBJECT)).removeItem(c);
                }
                
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Tried Other Solution (By adding only required resources on page):**

```
PDResources resources = copyResources(page);
COSDictionary pageObjects = (COSDictionary) resources.getCOSObject().getDictionaryObject(COSName.XOBJECT);
COSDictionary newObjects = new COSDictionary();

Set<String> imageNames = findImageNames(page);
Iterable<COSName> xObjectNames = resources.getXObjectNames();
for (COSName xObjectName : xObjectNames) {
    System.out.println(xObjectName);
    if (resources.isImageXObject(xObjectName)) {
        Boolean used = imageNames.contains(xObjectName);
        if (used) {
            newObjects.setItem(xObjectName, pageObjects.getItem(xObjectName));
        } else {
             System.out.println("Found unused image: name={}"+xObjectName.getName());
        }
    } else {
        newObjects.setItem(xObjectName, pageObjects.getItem(xObjectName));
    }
}
resources.getCOSObject().setItem(COSName.XOBJECT, newObjects);
page.setResources(resources);
```

Comment: I have also followed this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47757971/how-to-remove-a-specific-image-from-a-pdf-with-pdfbox but it didn't help.

Comment: You say image. Do you mean bitmap image? Or is it possibly a vector graphics image? Is that image in some annotation or is it in the static page content? Furthermore, is it stored in some resource dictionary or is it stored inline in some content stream?

Comment: @mkl first of all thanks for your response. Yes, it is stored inline in the content stream. I used PDPageContentStream and PDImageXObject classes to draw image.

Comment: Ah, so you know exactly how the image was added to the pdf? That would have been a great information to have added to your question... Nonetheless, having *used PDPageContentStream and PDImageXObject classes to draw image* does not automatically mean the image is stored inlined. More likely it is stored as a resource referenced from the content stream in question. To be sure, please share the pivotal code of adding the image in the first place. Furthermore, please describe how you plan to recognize which image to remove.

Comment: @mkl I'm using the below code to remove an image from the page. It has worked to remove the specific image and I'm using metadata for the conditional check. But after saving the document and opening the saved document it gives a warning like - **" An error exists on this page. Acrobat may not display the page correctly."**  

***However, after removing that warning popup the doc shows with a removed image.***

Comment: Also, I'm unable to edit my question. I was about to show you my code through it. But don't know the edit option is not visible there. Even I can't post my answer as well.

Comment: *"Also, I'm unable to edit my question"* - there is an [edit] link right underneath.

Comment: *"I'm using the below code"* - which *below code*?

Comment: @mkl thanks for your continuous guidance. I added code in the question summary. It works but as I said it gives the aforementioned warning.

Comment: OK. So you only remove the image resource, but the (then removed) resource is still referenced from the content stream. You definitively should also remove the reference.

Comment: Could you please tell me how we can achieve it? The sample code will be appreciated as I'm the first time working on the PDFBox library.

Comment: @mkl I tried another solution by adding only the required images into the page. (That piece of code also added in question summary) It also gives the same warning message as earlier. In an earlier comment, you mentioned that **the (then removed) resource is still referenced from the content stream. You definitively should also remove the reference.** But I have really no idea where I can do it within my code.

Comment: The content stream references the images in **Do** instructions which the question you reference tried to remove. But instead of removing both the references from the content stream and the image xobjects themselves from the resources, you could alternatively replace the image xobjects in the resources by empty form xobjects.